# SQLException after connection left idle

Tags: java, jdbc, db2, sqlexception

I am using DB2 with JDBC and the below code throws SQLException when I try to run for the first time after I left the connection idle for a few minutes. From the second time onward it would work exactly the way it has to.

`ResultSet.next()`

Any ideas on what would cause the exception?

Exception trace:

```
FFDC Exception:com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.lo SourceId:com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcResultSet.next 
ProbeId:2624 Reporter:
com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJccResultSet@b080b08
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.lo: The current transaction was rolled back because of error "-30108".. SQLCODE=-1476, SQLSTATE=40506, DRIVER=3.57.110
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.bd.a(bd.java:663)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.bd.a(bd.java:60)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.bd.a(bd.java:127)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.am.b(am.java:3760)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.eb.h(eb.java:278)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.eb.a(eb.java:239)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.eb.c(eb.java:31)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.u.a(u.java:32)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.j.Zb(j.java:259)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.am.X(am.java:3554)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.d.f(d.java:1881)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gc.a(gc.java:200)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.d.a(d.java:109)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.am.c(am.java:366)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.am.next(am.java:293)
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcResultSet.next(WSJdbcResultSet.java:3120)
```

Comment: Without seeing exception details it is hard to tell what is going on. But one possible cause could be querying on stale connection.

Comment: Please see edit for details

Answer (score 3):

The "outer" [SQL Code, `-1476`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql01476n.html), indicates that the transaction was rolled back because of the "inner" [SQL Code, `-30108`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql30108n.html), which says:

> A connection failed but has been re-established. Special register
>   settings might have been replayed. Host name or IP address of the new
>   connection: host-name. Service name or port number of the new
>   connection: service-name. Reason code: reason-code.

I would guess that your connection timed out, and it dropped.

Comment: I could get the connection and it's not `null` neither do I get any `SQLException` in `getConnection()` method, it only fails at `ResultSet.next()`

Comment: Yeah, the docs say the connection will be re-established, but the program "is responsible for re-building session resources", which likely means that your result set will have been closed, thus, it can't fetch the next record.